# Relationship between tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I use `sqlmembership provider` and that creates some tables. I need its `user` table.

My application has three types of users: `teachers`, `students` and `other users`. So I thought of three tables for them.

Each of them has a `username` which is registered by membership provider and saved in its own tables.

Now I don't know how to make the relationship between `teachers` or `students` tables to their usernames saved in the table of memberships, using entity framework.

I thought I can add a one to one relationship between `users` table created by membership provider and my tables after reverse engineering created tables by it to code first, but it seems is not allowed to change those tables.

**Can someone show me how to make a relationship between teachers or students to their usernames *(I mean their membership information)*?**

**More Details: here are code first tables**

```
public class aspnet_Users
{
    public aspnet_Users()
    {
        this.aspnet_PersonalizationPerUser = new List<aspnet_PersonalizationPerUser>();
        this.aspnet_Roles = new List<aspnet_Roles>();
    }

    public System.Guid ApplicationId { get; set; }
    public System.Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string LoweredUserName { get; set; }
    public string MobileAlias { get; set; }
    public bool IsAnonymous { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime LastActivityDate { get; set; }
    public virtual aspnet_Applications aspnet_Applications { get; set; }
    public virtual aspnet_Membership aspnet_Membership { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<aspnet_PersonalizationPerUser> aspnet_PersonalizationPerUser { get; set; }
    public virtual aspnet_Profile aspnet_Profile { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<aspnet_Roles> aspnet_Roles { get; set; }
}

public class Techer
{
    [Key]
    public int TeacherId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string NationalNumber { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int OfficeId { get; set; }
    public virtual Office Office { get; set; }
}

public class Student
{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int OfficeId { get; set; }
    public virtual Office Office { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've encountered a similar scenario, and what I ended up doing is creating a foreign key from my user profile table(s) to the membership table. So for example, the Teacher table would have a column called MembershipId, and it would foreign key to the Id column in the membership table. Then, in the Register action of my AccountController, I have something like this:

```
if (db.Memberships.Any(x => x.UserName == model.UserName) 
{
    // handle error here
    // return view with error message "user name already in use"
}

var token = WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password, null, true);
var membership = db.Memberships.SingleOrDefault(x => x.UserName == model.UserName);
if (membership != null) 
{
    var newProfile = new Teacher
    {
        Membership = membership
        // add other properties here if required
    }
    db.Teachers.Add(newProfile);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

*This code is untested, as I don't have VS available at the moment, but should be enough to get you on the right track.

Comment: thanks @Will, so it is a one to one relationship? we know that a username should belong to one person, does this prevent using that username by someone else in another table (i.e Students)?

Comment: @Blazi: Yes, it is a one-to-one relationship. I've added a snippet to the answer that will ensure a username cannot be used more than once.

Comment: @Will i am confused, i have been working on similar model as this but i can't make it work using your example. As i understand, membership has no `UserName`, the only similar column they have is `UserId`, which is not present in the `RegisterModel`. So how can you instantiate the membership variable? I have also tried to pull `foreign key` from `UserProfile`, it doesn't work hence trying this.

Comment: @KomengeMwandila With your model, try taking the returned token from the CreateUserAndAccount method and searching for it in the Membership table ConfirmationToken column.

Comment: @Will that worked, thanks alot, i have been sitting on this for weeks. If i could i would give you more that +1